# ASP.NET Web API Attribute Routing: RoutePrefix with Route Parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net, attributerouting

Is it possible in ASP.NET to have a RoutePrefix attribute on an ApiController that contains a route parameter?

```
[RoutePrefix("api/parent/{pid}/child")]
public class ChildController : ApiController
{
    [Route("")]
    public HttpResponseMessage Get(object pid)
    {
        //...
    }

    [Route("{cid}"]
    public HttpResponseMessage Get(object pid, object cid)
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

I would like to have the pid parameter accessible to all controller methods.

Comment: I was able to get this to work if I type the parameter ( {pid:int} ) and have the input parameter be an integer rather than an object.

Why does it not work as written above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use `object` as the parameter type because Web API doesn't know how to convert a string to an object. You have to use a simple type such as `int`, `string`, `Guid`, etc. If you want to use a complex type, you have to use the `FromUri` attribute or write a custom converter for it.

More info on http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api